# Show that the law of the excluded middle does not hold in a BCCC

Tags: logic, category-theory, intuitionistic-logic

I want to show that the law of the excluded middle do not hold in a bicartesian closed category (BCCC), interpreted as follows:

> In general, there need not be a morphism $1 \to A + 0^A$ for $A \in \text{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ in a BCCC $\mathcal{C}$.

Well, this is obviously true, because we can see Heyting algebras as BCCCs (in fact, I guess they are indeed equivalent as categories).  And if there exists one such a morphism for each object $A$, then each Heyting algebras would be a Boolean algebra.

But is there a more direct proof of this statement?

Comment: this isn't indirect at all-to prove something need not hold, you just need to give an example.